# Is there a difference between splice-site mutations, and non-stop mutations

Tags: bioinformatics, mutations

I'm working on a bioinformatics project where a lot of the biology I've had to learn from scratch. From my current understanding, a non-stop mutation alters a stop codon such that the transcription [continues](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3525242/), and a splice site mutation alters the region between introns and exons - where the sequence may include introns, or remove part of the exons [from cancer.gov](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/genetics-dictionary/def/splice-site-variant#:~:targetText=NCI%20Dictionary%20of%20Genetics%20Terms,-The%20NCI%20Dictionary&targetText=A%20genetic%20alteration%20in%20the,Also%20called%20splice%2Dsite%20mutation.). I'm inferring therefore that these could be the same mutation type.

Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those kinds of mutations are quite distinct.  Also, you misstate the nature of a [nonstop mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_codon#Nonstop_mutations); the change of a stop codon affects termination of *translation*, not *transcription*.  This is quite different from a splice-site mutation, which affects [splicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_splicing), a form of mRNA processing that occurs between transcription and translation.

Comment: Great thanks for clearing that up